# Showing an Flutter Alert Dialog Without the need to open Flutter App

Tags: flutter

How to display an alert dialog when I click on a link in another app without the need to open my flutter app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Receive share intent plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) to get url, image, text and more to open into your app.

Comment: Yes, it could read all domain that you have mentioned in the Android Manifest file.